# Reading a javascript dict into Python

Tags: javascript, python

I have a file `file.js` which contains:

```js
Foo.bar = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
}
```

I would like to read the dict into Python. I've come up with

```
from pathlib import Path
import json

txt = Path('file.js').read_text()
json.loads(txt[txt.find('{'):txt.find('}')+1])
```

it just feels hack-ish - is there a better way?

Comment: Is `file.js` always going to contain a single named object?

Comment: You can use regular expression. Or split by `=` and use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Why not just make `file.js` a json file that you can read into both languages?

Comment: @Marc-AndréBrochu yes

Comment: at least the find('}') should be rfind to cover nesting

Comment: @rasjani there's guaranteed to be no nesting. Unfortunately, I can't change the file type. Maybe `find` is good enough for this use-case then - thanks for your inputs!

Comment: You might find it more performant to read in all lines then omit the first line and then `loads` a string with a prefixed `{`. Alternatively you might find the second `.find()` isn't needed `txt[txt.find('{'):]`

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('file.js') as json_file:
    data = json_file.read()
    data_dict = eval(data[data.find("=") + 1:])
```

This considering that your file contains only a single json object, like on your example.

Comment: this code will raise an exception since the data in `file.json` is not a valid json

Comment: Edited, that should get the data after the "=" and store it as dict.